# Cannot resolve method between Enumerable and Queryable candidates

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-to-entities

I have this method in a class called Invoice:

```
public static Expression<Func<Invoice, bool>> IsAllocated()
{
    return i => i.TotalAmountDue == i.GetAllocationsTotal();
}
```

I have a list like this:

```
IQueryable<Invoice> invoices
```

And I need to filter it like that (it's Linq to Entity):

```
var filteredInvoices = invoices.Where(i => Invoice.IsAllocated());
```

In this line I'm getting two errors:

> Cannot resolve method ... candidates are .... one in Enumerable and the other on in Queryable.

And also:

> Cannot convert expression type `Expression<Func<Invoice,bool>>` to
>   return type 'bool'

I've tried a lot of things I've found in SO with no luck. Can someone say me what is missing here or at least, which one of the two errors is at the root of the problem?

Comment: I'll say that the next roadblock will be `i.GetAllocationsTotal()` :-)

Comment: @xanatos you are 100% right :)

Comment: To other googlers who land here, make sure you're using `==` and not `=` in your lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method returns an appropriate expression tree already - you just need to call it, not call it *in a lambda expression*:

```
var filteredInvoices = invoices.Where(Invoice.IsAllocated());
```

Comment: That was it, now I'm a step closer to understand _Lambda Expressions_. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Expression are representation and not delegate by themselves. You should create a delegate out of it first

```
static Expression<Func<Invoice, bool>> IsAllocatedExpr()
{
    return i => i.TotalAmountDue == i.GetAllocationsTotal();
}

public static Func<Invoice, bool> IsAllocated = IsAllocatedExpr().Compile();
```

and then

```
var filteredInvoices = invoices.Where(i => Invoice.IsAllocated(i));
```

Comment: No, the OP *wants* it as an expression tree - the point is to pass the expression tree to the LINQ provider to filter at the database.

Comment: Aaah, there you are again.... was the need for the expression tree written in an invisible ink here. Can't see that on the question..

Comment: Well if the OP *did* just want a delegate, why would they go to the trouble of making an expression tree? And why would they want to force the query to be performed client-side when it doesn't need to be? It simply doesn't make any sense, given the context we have (EF and an `IQueryable<T>`...)

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right, all the complexity in this task is coming from the need to use Linq to Entities so the work is done in the DB server.